# How much Aether is used when attacking in an Aether Raid?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

I'm having fun with the new Aether Raids mode,
However I seem to be having too much fun as my Aether seems to burn out fast when I make multiple attacks.
After attacking a few times it appears that my Aether is going down by a random number each time:
I went from 106 Aether to 75,
then from 75 to 39.

This does not include the Aether I gained,
as I then went up to 46 Aether,
Made another attack which brought me down to 9, but in that attack I got back some Aether so I'm sitting at 12.
So the cost was 46 - 9 = 35 Aether.

With 12 Aether I click to make another attack, and I get a prompt saying "You need 38 Aether to make an attack"

So my first attack cost 31 Aether, by next attack cost 34 Aether, and then 35 Aether, finally if I could make another attack it would be 38 Aether.

I'm attacking with one unit from the bonus units only. (The other 3 units are not bonus units)

**Is there anything that affects how much Aether it costs to make an attack?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer,

The First attack each day is free.
Each subsequent attack costs an amount of Aether based on your current Lift : [image]

This means if you have 3001 to 3100 lift, it would cost 40 Aether to attack.

Also as you progress and your lift increases, it takes more Aether to attack.